# Shared Device status is showing as offline in Alexa for Business console

Tags: alexa-for-business

I have developed an amazon skill which I have published as private and now i want to use that via Alexa device.

As per documentation, I have enabled Alexa for Business in AWS account and executed   Alexa for Business Device Setup Tool exe file and there it shows Alexa device successfully connected as status.

Whereas When I return to Alexa for Business console it shows the device listed now but with status as offline.

I tried communicating with Alexa device which was happening smoothly which means it was connected to internet by not visible in A4B account.

Is there anything I am missing?

Since A4B is only available in US East region, does that mean Internet IP should belong to that region?